# API going into 502 Gateway timeout on AWS EKS when high load

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, kubernetes, timeout, amazon-eks

I've currently deployed a REST api onto a EKS cluster with ExternalDNS, HPA, VPA, Cluster Autoscaler etc.. and I am facing a big issue regarding load.

I did a few load tests by swarming the api with requests, the problem is that:

1. the api seems extremely slow to respond (i have the same api deployed on another platform and performs significantly better
2. After a few requests, they all start to return 502 timeout.

I know for a fact it is not a problem of CPU or memory usage since the pods have 1vCPU and 1 Gb of memory and they don't use not even 20% of it.

In grafana i see the kube-proxy receiving those requests and some get the needed response, but the others fail.

What could the problem be? Any help/advice is much appreciated

Comment: its not limited to the service it self, it might involve DB etc. better to add flow, how the request come and how the path looks like for the request.  whats the default timeout on the LB? whats the default timeout on the application side etc etc

Comment: Since i'm a begginner in this, how can i find the flow of the request?

Comment: which endpoint are you hitting to produce load? does this endpoint contain any code of connecting with db etc?